# Can someone please explain this code segment?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void removeNode(string sk2) {
  nodelist *nodePtr, *previousNode;  // keeps the list in memory

  if (head->SKU == sk2) {
    nodePtr = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = nodePtr;
  } else {
    nodePtr = head;

    previousNode = NULL;

    while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->SKU != sk2) {
      previousNode = nodePtr;
      nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
    previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
    delete nodePtr;
  }
}
```

Sorry if its in the wrong format, im new to this site and c++ in general. I cant seem to understand how this linked list preforms the delete function.

Comment: Is this a member function? It looks like `head` is a member variable or else I don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code it is deleting the node of the linked list which is having its value as `sk2` passed from calling function.

I have put comments on it please refer if something is not clear you can ask me :)

```
  void removeNode(string sk2){ // function having string as a argument 

    nodelist *nodePtr, *previousNode; //keeps the list in memory Variable of type nodelist 


 // here it is checking with the head of the link list whether that matches with the argument, as all linked list start with the Head 

    if (head->SKU == sk2){  
       nodePtr = head->next;
       delete head;  // if so then delete that node
       head = nodePtr;  // and reassign the head to new node 
    } 

 // if head parameter is not matching 
    else 
    {
       nodePtr = head;

       previousNode = NULL;

     // travel up-to the node which has a data as a string passed as argument 
       while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->SKU != sk2)
       {

         previousNode = nodePtr;
         nodePtr = nodePtr->next; 
       }   
        previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;  // if found then delete that node 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to remove a node which has `sk2` as `SKU` member.

The first `if` just checks if the `head` node is the one and deletes it if it is.

If not then the else block is trying to find it. `nodePtr` is then the current node to check and the loop condition is: "as long as i have a node to check and it's not the right one".
So the loop just gets the `->next` element every time. Also the loop always keeps the previous node because the `->next` field will have to be set accordingly.

If the loop finishes either one of two things will happen:

1. The `nodePtr` contains the right node and it will be delted and the links restored in a valid fashion
2. The `nodePtr` is `NULL`. Then undefined behaviour will occur.